Firebase custom push notifications in service worker show 2 notifications
I'm facing the following issue with custom push notifications using Firebase: For some reason both the original notification that I receive from the backend as well as the customized notification are shown. I only want to show the custom one.
Whenever I set requireInteraction: true in the custom notification, the original message gets shown as well, so 2 notifications. When I remove the requireInteraction it only shows the custom notification. However I don't want the notification to close automatically.
Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?
This is the code I'm using in the service worker:
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.13.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  // config
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  if (event.data) {
    const notificationTitle = 'Custom Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'This is a custom notification',
      icon: '/firebase-logo.png',
      // FIXME:
      // When this is uncommented 2 notifications are shown 
      // requireInteraction: true,
    };

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions));
  }
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  console.log('Notification clicked:', event);
  event.notification.close();

  // You can add custom click handling here
});

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Received background message:', payload);
  // Returning false to suppress default notification
  return false;
});


